# How to not include row name when using rowMeans for dataframe in R

Tags: r

```
temp = as.data.frame(t(marks))
rownames(temp) = c("John", "Mary", "Mark", "June", "Claire", "Anthony")
names(temp) = c("Module1", "Module2","Module3","Module4","Module5")
rowMeans(temp["June",])
```

[Here's the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZW6x.png)

The output of the rowMeans include row name, is there any way to not include that. I only want the value.
the current output is

```
June 
87.2
```

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `unname`

```
unname(rowMeans(temp["June",]))
```

or another option is `as.vector` which strips off the attributes as well

```
as.vector(rowMeans(temp["June",]))
```